# Class Design for Transformers

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

Am sure that , everyone will be aware of the Transformers ( Optimus Prime , Megatron etc).

Am trying to represent that in the form of classes and interface. For now, am not considering the attributes. Am just taking some functionalities.

My Design is

```
interface Car{
 public void run();
 public void stop();
}

interface Robot{
 public void walk();
 public void fight();
}

class Transformer implements Car, Robot {
 // implementing all the methods
}
```

So the class `Transformer` says, it can perform both Car and Robot operations

During instantiation

```
Robot R = new Transformer(); // Now the transformer is in Robot format
Car C = new Transformer();  // Now the transformer is in Car format
```

My Question is ,here two objects that are getting created `Robot R` and `Car C`. So, this convey the Robot is **getting created** and Car is **getting created** . But what I want is `The Car is Getting Transformed to A Robot and Vice Versa`

How to implement this in design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got some shape here...

But the problem here is, the transformer WALKS explicitly and the CAR runs explicitly.Which says, they are two different objects. I want them, thats it!

```
public class TransformersClass{

    public TransformersClass() {

        Car transformer = new Transformer(); // Initially they are Cars
        Robot robot = (Robot) transformer; // Now transformed to Robot. No new objects are created

    }

}

class Transformer implements Robot, Car {


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void walk() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void attack() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void fire() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}


interface Robot {
    public void walk();
    public void attack();
    public void fire();

}

interface Car {
    public void run();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, you want the Transformer class to have either Robot functionality OR Car functionality but not both at the same time.

To model that, I would favor [Composition over Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance).

e.g.:

```
class Transformer {

private Car car;
private Robot robot;
private Class currentState = Car.class;

 public void fight() {
   if (currentState.equals(Robot.class)
      robot.fight();
   }

 public void drive() {
  if (currentState.equals(Car.class)
      car.drive();
  }

 public void transform() {
  if (currentState.equals(Car.class) 
      currentState = Robot.class;
  else
      currentState = Car.class;
}
```

To instantiate a new Transformer, you would need to define its Car-Form and its Robot-Form, e.g.:

```
new Transformer(new OptimusPrimeRobot(), new GiantTruck());
```

with the Constructor:

```
Transformer(Robot r, Car c) {
   this.robot = r;
   this.car = c;
}
```

with OptimusPrimeRobot implementing Robot and GiantTruck implementing Car.

If you want, you can even lazy initialize your contained classes. Define fields:

```
Class carClass;
Class robotClass;
```

and a Constructor:

```
Transformer(Class robotC, Class carC) {
   this.robotClass = robotC;
   this.carClass = carC;
}
```

Then make getter Methods for Robot and Car:

```
private Robot getRobot() {
  if(robot == null) {
     robot = robotClass.newInstance();
  }
  return robot;
}
```

and adjust your code, so it uses the Getters instead of the fields:

```
   getRobot().fight();
```

Now you just specify what Classes your Transformer consists of and their objects are only instantiated when needed.

Comment: +1 for Hitting the bulls eye "Mutual Exclusion either Car or Robot"

Comment: Can you tell how u will instantiate the transformer

Comment: I've added an example. You would actually end up with 3 objects instead of one, but each would have it's distinct role and the composition makes sure their functionalities don't overlap.

Comment: new OptimusPrimeRobot(), new GiantTruck()); 

Two objects here :(

Comment: new Transformer(..) as well, as I said, 3 objects BUT a) Transformer is composed of the other 2 objects and each of those only carries half of the functionlity, making your resulting class carry no redundancy(like in your example with the 2 transformers) and b) Composition makes it easier to refactor.

Comment: Transformer is composed of the other 2 objects - Brilliant!! But this just creates an illusion but eventually what happens it, two objects are getting created and they getting switched accordingly

Comment: You could also do lazy initialization by making a constructor that accepts: new Transformer(OptimusPrimeRobot.class, GiantTruck.class); , so you can instantiate the objects with Reflection when you need them.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldnt have the Car transforming to a Robot. A Car is nothing but a Car and shouldnt know anything of Robots. But you can have a Transformer transform to Car or a Robot. I dont see why you need it but you could make something like this:

```
class Transformer implements Car, Robot {

  public Car transformToCar() {
     return (Car)this;
  }

  public Robot transformToRobot() {
    return (Robot) this;
  }
}
```

so then you could do:

```
Transformer optimus = new Transformer();
Car optimusCar = optimus.transformToCar();
//but this is the same as writing:
Car optimusCar = (Car) optimus;
```

As you can see the transformToXXX() methods really doesnt make sense as the Transformer always are both Car and Robot.

EDIT: You could of course move the transformToCar() definition into Robot and transformToRobot() definition into Car. Transformer class would then have to implement those methods.

Comment: What about the implementation?? Am asking the Transformer to "Move".... If its a Car it should "Run"...If its a Robo , it should walk... But the method is same "Move" but the implementation is different

Answer (score 1):

Extend the Car interface with a transformation method:

```
interface TransformableCar extends Car {

    TransformableRobot asRobot();
}
```

Extend the Robot interface with a transformation method:

```
interface TransformableRobot extends Robot {

    TransformableCar asCar();
}
```

Create a class with two inner classes representing the two states:

```
public class Megatron {

    private MegatronCar car = new MegatronCar();
    private MegatronRobot robot = new MegatronRobot();

    public TransformableCar asCar() {
        return car;
    }

    public TransformableRobot asRobot() {
        return robot;
    }

    class MegatronCar implements TransformableCar {

        @Override
        public TransformableRobot asRobot() {
            return Megatron.this.asRobot();
        }

        // TODO: Implement Car methods
    }

    class MegatronRobot implements TransformableRobot {

        @Override
        public TransformableCar asCar() {
            return Megatron.this.asCar();
        }

        // TODO: Implement Robot methods
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Megatron megatron = new Megatron();
TransformableCar car = megatron.asCar();
TransformableRobot robot = car.asRobot();
```

Comment: You are not transforming :). You are creating new objects in asRobot and asCar methods.

Comment: Well, it is transforming from the client's point of view, but I've edited to make it clearer.

Comment: Hey!. This is what saying. A new Robot is getting created but it is not getting transformed to Robot

Comment: From the client's point of view, it has a car, it calls asRobot() and now it has a robot. The car has effectively transformed into a robot. It's type-safe and if Robot and Car both define a stop() method (say) there can be different implementations for it without any worries about clashing, which you would have in your implementation.

Comment: But after transforming i want to listen to my favorite channels that i had book marked before transforming to Robot.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the [strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern
`Transformer` would be a concrete class, which would delegate functionality to a `RobotStrategy` or `CarStrategy`. Both these would implement a `TransformerStrategy`

```
public interface TransformerStrategy{
    public void move();//implemented by both
    public void stop();//implemented by both
    public void fight();//implemented by only Robot, NO-OP for car
    //etc
}
```

Comment: Car cannot fight ( Plz dont say it can RAM)

Comment: NO-OP means no implementation. there is no after effect of calling it

Comment: So, it implicitly say for example Car can fight but it does not know how to fight :(

Comment: Agreed. An UnsupportedOperationException (which is a java.lang class used extensively through the jdk for such scenarios) would be a better response.

Answer (score 1):

**Decorator Pattern.** Like in Collections class.
Use static methods.

```
public static Robot transformCar(Car car){
        return (Robot)car;
    }
```

Comment: How will you cast Car as Robot.

Comment: @madhairsilence car is a Transformer implements Car, Robot. It can be a car or a robot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to describe your use cases at bit more.

To me, there is little in common between the Car and the Robot. If it's currently a Car, I want it to call run and stop, if it's a Robot to call walk and fight. I don't want a design that allows me to call the wrong method when it's in an incorrect state and I can't imagine the behaviours I would want to call in both states. That almost sounds like a Transformer object composed of both a Car and Robot object, with a getter to return the current state. But maybe if you describe the use cases more something different would be suitable. Interesting question.

Comment: Its not about isolating the common method. It is about making the object transform than creating a new one